# How do you use ”～じゃんよ。” and what exactly does it mean?

Tags: grammar, usage, nuances, anime, role-language

At the end of sentences in casual form I know you can use ～じゃない or ～じゃん to say "~isn't it?" similar to ～ね. And I know ～よ at the end of a sentence can be used like "I tell you" or for emphasis, but what happens when you use ～じゃんよ at the end of a sentence, like in the titles of Space Dandy episodes (the examples below)? The official English episode titles all end with ", baby" so I feel like it's a speech pattern of someone who considers themself kinda cool. E.g.

> 流れ流されて生きるじゃんよ
> Live with the Flow, Baby
>
> 幻の宇宙ラーメンを探すじゃんよ
> The Search for the Phantom Space Ramen, Baby
>
> 騙し騙される事もあるじゃんよ
> Occasionally Even the Deceiver Is Deceived, Baby

Answer (score 4):

The titles are non-standard Japanese (they are creative sentences). I for one think the translations are as good as it gets.

In normal contexts they are used like this:

> 受験失敗したのは自分のせいじゃんよ
>   (Lecturing) The reason you failed was your own fault, isn't it hey?
>
> 安っぽい店で飲みたいこともあるじゃんよ
>   (Defending) Sometimes you wanna drink in a cheap place, don't we hey?

It generally sounds confident because you are asserting the fact, which is has a patronizing effect. I think that's why the translation adds "baby", and I think it does reflect the tone pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

じゃん/じゃんよ is a kind of dialect around Tokyo, Kanagawa and Yamanashi Prefecture. Many young people (including me) commonly use じゃん in casual conversation. I feel じゃんよ is less popular than じゃん.

(1) talking common topic

> 「明日パーティーあるじゃん？何時に集合にする？」
>   ("You know, we're gonna party tommorow? What time can we meet together?")

(2) expressing feeling

> 「これおいしいじゃん！」
>   ("Yummy!")

(3) (casually) blaming

> 「そんなことしたらだめじゃん」
>   ("You shouldn't do such thing.")

(4) asking someone's approval

> 「やっぱりそう思うじゃん？」
>   ("You think so too?")

Comment: 元来は三河弁であり、それが神奈川、更には東京へと伝わったというのが定説のようです。

Comment: OP asked about the meaning and usage of "じゃんよ。" and the only words related to this phrase from you are "I feel じゃんよ is less popular than じゃん."

Comment: The provided examples are very good, and helped non-native speakers to get the feel of this expression in colloquial sentences.